# innerHTML not working javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml

I have already found some question of this genre but the answer didn't help.

[Javascript - div content without innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822183/javascript-div-content-without-innerhtml)

[Javascript: Does not change the div innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157983/javascript-does-not-change-the-div-innerhtml)

I have a div called adx-title by id and i have to change the content. So i made my ajax call and i stored (i use jQuery) in a call the title i want this div to contain:

```
$('#adx-title').inneHTML = title;
```

Firebug report this ($('#adx-title').inneHTML) as undefined, and it does report so in every attempt i make to change the content of the div, which is read as an object but it doesn't have the innerHTML property. The script is loaded after i click a button so it should recognize the div as already loaded by the page. And indeed it gets the div with $('#adx-title'). it just doesn't apply the change and reports innerHTML as undefined. 
Anyone has had a similar issue? Anyone can help? Thanks Agnese

Answer (score 4):

You're using jQuery.

```
$('#adx-title').html( title );
```

The `.innerHTML` property is part of the DOM API. When you make a call to jQuery (as you're doing with the `$`) the result is a jQuery object, not a DOM element.

You can get the DOM element from the jQuery object like this:

```
var elem = $('#adx-title').get(0);
```

However, the jQuery `.html()` API wraps access to the `.innerHTML` property and also provides some other useful bookkeeping features. If you're using jQuery in general to manipulate the DOM, it's a good idea to use `.html()` and not the raw DOM API for that reason.

Comment: Your last sentence is quite possibly the most important!

Answer (score 3):

Try `$('#adx-title').html(title);`